# how to get user input as a value in jq in shell script

Tags: shell, jq

I have a JSON file from which I am trying to get a value using below

```
[a223180n@363748ln41dk012 ~]$ cat status.json| jq  '.details.server1.status'
"UP"
```

In my script, I have the option where the user will enter the server name. So I need the script to pick that value and update the jq command accordingly I am using below and it is failing.

jq is 1.6 version

```
[a223180n@363748ln41dk012 ~]$ cat status.json| jq --arg server server1'.details.$server.status'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.details.$service.status
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Is the missing whitespace in here also missing in your real program?

Comment: Don't use single quotes if you want a variable to be interpolated.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, but they *shouldn't* have the variable interpolated by the shell here; it should be expanded by jq.

Comment: ...however, correct syntax to do that would be `echo '{"key": "value"}' | jq --arg k "key" '.[$k]'` -- or `'.details[$k].status'`, with their undisclosed real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
< status.json jq --arg server server1 '.details[$server].status'
```

The dot operator is a special version of the `[]` operator that only works with *literal* keys. You have a variable for a key here, so you need the `[]` operator.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy UUOC eliminated, just for you. :)

Comment: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>,

Comment: @oguzismail, the original piped from `cat`, and I complained.

Comment: @Charles nice, but jq can read filenames from command line, is there an advantage of redirecting from a file over specifiying it on the command line?

Comment: No particular advantage, no.